# Match paths that do not have __magic__ folders

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, webpack

I have a tree of components and inside of that tree are `__magic_names__` folders (e. g. `__tests__`, `__fixtures__`, etc.).  I want to filter out any files inside of these `__magic_names__` folders. I'm using webpack and using [`require.context`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#require-context) to slurp up my components - and I don't want my tests to ship with my production code.

I have the following regular expression, which is *supposed* to filter out every file path that contains a double-underscore.  Unfortunately, it matches paths with `__magic__` folders too:

```
^./((?!=__)[^/]+?(?!=__)/)*((?!=__)[^/]+?(?!=__)).jsx?$
```

#### Should work:

```
./SomeComponent.js
./SomeComponent.jsx
./SomeComponent/SomeComponent.js
./SomeComponent/SomeComponent.jsx
./SomeComponent/ChildComponent/Child.js
./SomeComponent/ChildComponent/Child.jsx
```

#### Should fail

```
./__magic__/SomeComponent.js
./__magic__/SomeComponent.jsx
./SomeComponent/__magic__/SomeComponent.js
./SomeComponent/__magic__/SomeComponent.jsx
./SomeComponent/__magic__/ChildComponent/Child.js
./SomeComponent/__magic__/ChildComponent/Child.jsx
./SomeComponent/ChildComponent/__magic__/Child.js
./SomeComponent/ChildComponent/__magic__/Child.jsx
```

[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lJBNsZHK6XTVc2O8) visualizes it this way:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

And here's a link to the [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lJBNsZHK6XTVc2O8) for those who want to play around with it in more detail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try [`/^(?!.*\/__[^_]+__\/)\.\/.*\.jsx?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/eC8eC3/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it turns out that the issue was simply that I was using the wrong syntax for negative look-aheads.  `(?!=__)` is wrong, `(?!__)` is right.

The corrected regular expression:

```
^./((?!__)[^/]+?(?!__)/)*((?!__)[^/]+?(?!__)).jsx?$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just match everything that doesn't have a double underscore like this.

```
/^((?!__).)*$/gm
```